# Weirdest IE bug ever? -- hovering a link causes page elements to jump up and cover others

Tags: css, internet-explorer, debugging

Ok, I've been dealing with IE bugs for a long time now, but this one is beyond me.  IE 7 and even 8 does it for sure, I've not seen it on FF or Chrome.

So here's a live URL which produces it:  http://mog.com/music/America/Holiday

Reproducing isn't easy, it can take a few times to make it happen.  Watch your scrollbar to see it change size so you know the page length was suddenly dropped quite a bit.

Here's how you do it:

1. Hover over any sub-nav link (Main, Albums, Songs, Photos, News, etc.)
2. Try them until you see the scrollbar change size.  Once it does, scroll all the way down and notice the footer has jumped up on top of much of the page content.
3. Be careful scrolling down that you don't roll over a few other page elements that will suddenly fix this.  So far I can see that any of the Play buttons will somehow fix this.

It's just beyond weird.  How could a rollover state cause this kind of behavior?

I've tried:

1. Removing the a:hover style - THIS FIXES IT... WTF?  Of course we ideally would keep some hover state, so hoping to avoid this fix.
2. Reproducing the hover functionality using jQuery hover(). - THIS DOESN'T FIX IT.

I figure the clues are in the elements that somehow magically fix it...and possibly in where the page jumps to, what elements suddenly get obscured by the footer.

Lastly, I didn't produce this site from scratch and it uses a lot of absolute and relative positioning for certain things and I know that is partly what causes these weird bugs.  I rarely, rarely use esp absolute positioning to avoid these kinds of bugs, but it's a bit too late now.

Thanks for anyone willing to check it out!!

Answer (score 5):

Well, I figured it out.  It was an odd case of the "Guillotine" bug.  One I luckily haven't come across before.  Turns out the "special" CSS rules on those nav links' hover state (particularly it seemed the border and bg image) were enough to trip this bug.  One way around was to drop those styles, but not ideal.  The real fix, however, was an unsemantic clearing div placed in just the right spot.  More info found here:

http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/guillotine.html

Answer (score -1):

Hi just a short note: When did you validate your html the last time?
As you probably know, but might have forgotten, fixing your html can sometimes solve a lot of problems. There are 72 errors seen by http://validator.w3.org

Comment: nice reminder, thanks!  i haven't read it over well yet, but i might be the victim of the following:  http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/guillotine.html